Does Germany have year round application system for PhD program in Mathematics?
I have completed my masters in mathematics from a institute in Asia. I will apply to Germany for PhD program in mathematics.

I wanted to know if Germany has a year round application system where I can write to professors year round or is there some specific months where I should write to them?

Kindly guide.

Take a look at the proposed duplicate. Regarding your core question, no, there is no specific date. Positions open year round. It's a bit more common for positions to start in October and April, corresponding to academic semesters, but it really depends on when financing starts, and when someone moves on from their position.

Actually you are partially true and the explanation could be given based on the type of PhD you are looking for. There are three types of PhD one can commonly find in Germany.

Structured Programs: Many universities in Germany offer structured PhD programs with specific application deadlines. These programs often have set start dates and application periods, which are typically announced on the program's website.

Individual Doctoral Positions: If you are seeking an individual PhD position (where you work directly under the supervision of a professor), there is more flexibility. Professors may accept inquiries and applications year-round, depending on their funding situation and current projects. It's advisable to check the professor's research group webpage or contact them directly to inquire about open positions, if there is any. BUT remember to get accepted, you need to come with really solid research plan.

Industrial Doctoral Positions: This often has a couple of partners including both universities and industries. Therefore, there is no set timeframe to apply. You need to be actively search on both university and industry's career portal/page to find the announcements.



"Actually you are partially true and the explanation could be given based on the type of PhD you are looking for." What does this refer to? The question seems not to include a statement that could be true/false.

From the OP statements, it seems he is not aware about the education system in Germany. This is why I tried to explain a bit as he might be considering option 2. But he should know that that is not the only option available.

Two notes: Putting the structured research programs first is weird because ~90% of the PhD positions are not in such programs, but of type 2 and 3. Type 3 is typically pursued by candidates already working in industry. Second, the sentence "BUT remember to get accepted, you need to come with really solid research plan." is problematic, because it's quite the opposite. If there is an open position available for "cold-calling" applicants, that will typically be in a third-party funded project, and then the research work has to fit to that project.

Are 1 and 3 common in math or very rare? Do you have the background to say? My guess would be that 2 is almost universal in math in Germany.
